# QTP I want to split that number into 13

Tags: split, qtp, hp-uft

below number has length of 39, I want to divide that to length 13 and Want to get that values. So I should get 3 values like A =0001098600250, b = 0001098600602, c=0001098600763. Can you please help me regarding this.  000109860025000010986006020001098600763

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve exactly, but the following should give you the desired results.

```
Dim reqnumber,A,B,C

reqnumber =  000109860025000010986006020001098600763
A = Left(reqnumber,13)  
B= Mid(reqnumber,14,27)
C= Right(reqnumber,26)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help butreqnumber =  000109860025000010986006020001098600763 (this number is dynamic, sometimes it is x/13  ) x may be 13 or 26 or 39 or 52 etc. I think we should find the length and then break down into 13. But I dono how to do that. Help me please

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your string will always be in multiples of 13

```
butreqnumber = "000109860025000010986006020001098600763"

Dim arr()
ReDim arr(Len(butreqnumber) / 13)
j = 1

For i = 0 To (UBound(arr) - 1)
    arr(i) = Mid(butreqnumber,j,13)
    j = j+13
Next
```

Comment: If it helped you, mark it as answered so that it helps future readers

Answer (score 0):

Tried little bit. I Hope this will help you.

Let `varNum` is that number. Final output `arrNums` is array of numbers after splitting

```
intLen= Len(varNum) ' get lenth of the variable
varNum=Cint(varNum) ' covert to integer
If(intLen Mod 13) then ' if it is not multiple of 13
  msgbox "number length is not multple of 13"
Else     ' if it is multiple of 13
  Dim arrNums()   ' initialsie array to store numbers
  cnt=intLen/13   ' get count of numbers to be splitted
  redim arrNums(cnt-1) 
  For i=1 to cnt   ' loop and split the variable
    arrNums(i-1)=Mid(varNum, 13*(i-1)+1, 13) ' store number in array
    'i=i+1
  Next   
End if
```

Comment: Thank you, In place of i = i+1, I commented that or else It is giving only odd array values. Thanks for all your help Kiran